# Enable SSO for application on AWS by integrating with on-premise AD

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, adfs

For a reporting application deployed on AWS it is required to enable SSO for the users to access it -

1. The users are to access the application from their office PCs only within the company network.
2. The application endpoints are protected by an API gateway to only allow access from internal company network.
3. Once the user clicks on the URL for the reporting application, the app should authenticate the logged in user with the enterprise AD to ensure that the logged in user is a valid one and that they belong to the correct AD groups that are allowed access to the application.
4. If the authentication and authorization check is passed then the application should allow access to the user or else prompt up a login page to enter the credentials manually.

Can you advise what would be the best approach to set this up ? We have ADFS deployed on our company infrastructure (not sure of the version) so was wondering if we could use that or instead rely on Windows Kerberos authentication to get tokens to allow the user access.
What would be a better approach or more importantly what would be faster to setup. Completely new to SSO and ADFS in general so appreciate your responses.

Thanks!
Raunak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use ADFS as it is much easier to integrate web apps with ADFS compare to Kerberos.

Kerberos might be tricky. I see you mentioned the reporting app will only be used from company's internal network, but you may still get into the troubles with Kerberos because it requires certain browser setup on the end user machines. On Windows you will have to ensure some IE settings:

- IE -> Internet Options -> Security -> Local intranet -> Custom Level -> Make sure you have **"Automatic logon only in Intranet zone"** is selected.
- IE -> Internet Options > Advanced -> make sure **"Enable Integrated Windows Authentication"** is on
- It is very likely that you will also need to add your reporting application URL to the list of intranet sites and trusted sites on each user's PC (in case you use a custom domain name for your app, i.e. not an local server name in your domain)
- Other browsers than IE may need a different setup, you can read [more details here](https://support.pingidentity.com/s/article/How-to-configure-supported-browsers-for-Kerberos-NTLM)

I believe it is also a bit more complicated to work with the AD groups as you can only get a user name from a Kerberos token. Then you will have to make an additional call directly to AD to find user's groups. With ADFS you can get groups right from the token (as claims).

Here is a good manual on how to integrate your web app with ADFS: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/adfs

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the explanation on ADFS vs Kerberos. ADFS in this scenario seems more appropriate for us since we don't have the dependency on the browser type and also can get the user name + AD group from the token. I'll read up a bit more on the implementation using ADFS and get back if I have any further questions. Have a great day!